# Would it be a bad practice to use less.js in a production site (client-side javascript compliler for LESS style-sheets)?

Tags: less

This script basically turns `.less` code into `.css` code. I think it will only cause problems if the user has javascript turned off, but do many people do that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just compile the `.less` into `.css` before putting it into a production environment. That way it will still display to those without JS enabled, and won't suffer the issues @Plynx mentioned.

As for compiling, there are some real-time compilers out there, specifically:

- For Mac - [less.app](http://incident57.com/less/)
- For Windows - [Less Parser](http://www.proving-ground.be/less/)

Both compile `.less` to `.css` on file save, which is awesome, and makes LESS easier to use!

Comment: @alexchenco I wrote a small script in PHP that can do render less and minify your css, it's called [renderless.php](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/renderless)

Comment: For Windows there are apps like winless and Prepros, that watch your LESS folder and compile them into CSS any time you save them.

Answer (score 3):

Many people do (I don't have exact numbers, but IIRC less than 4%), but you are under no obligation to provide functionality without javascript. Many of the more advanced sites today do not. It depends on what you are serving and who your audience is.

Of course it's great to provide this functionality if you can. I would be more concerned about the effect less.js will have on your site's load time. If you can't load the CSS until after the javascript, you have to delay rendering until the javascript runs, in order to avoid an unseemly transition from unstyled to styled.

You can have your .less files auto-compile into CSS whenever they are changed by using tools that watch directories.

Comment: The point about the unstyled/styled transition is the most important in my opinion (and because the CSS is never directly referenced/cached, you'll get this transition on every page)

Comment: I suppose you could hack it and keep a script block at the top of the page - I think if it's in the header and it's an external script without the `defer='defer'` attribute then it will block rendering. Compiling to CSS and using the CSS only is the safest - also less resources to download.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're building and who your target audience is. Modern browsers that support HTML5 will cache the generated CSS the first time it loads so if the majority of your visitors will be using modern browsers it's pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

Other options is making your own less compiler in server and then you can "play" with cache times css results.

You can check libraries as LessPHP in order to do that.