# Is there a performance hit when i use LESS directly on my html pages?

Tags: html, css, less

Would compiling less client side slow down the loading of html pages significantly?

And is it wise to compile .less files beforehand and deploy it as a css?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="stlye.less" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.30.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would it be a bad practice to use less.js in a production site (client-side javascript compliler for LESS style-sheets)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482682/would-it-be-a-bad-practice-to-use-less-js-in-a-production-site-client-side-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105033/less-css-performance-and-implementation

Comment: You must compile LESS files before and in your HTML load it like CSS. If you use mac, there a great tool for that... [CodeKit](https://incident57.com/codekit/) and if you don't have mac you can use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)